# How do you perform Map/Reduce in Couchbase with the Node SDK?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I'm having a hard time experimenting with the node sdk, [the documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-node-1.2/) doesn't seem to be well maintained and the map/reduce examples just say

> First, create your view definition using by the web UI (though you may
>   also do this directly from the Node.js SDK, as will be shown later).

I don't want to be stuck using the web UI so would really appreciate if someone could give me  a quick example, or point me in the right direction.

Comment: See this example: https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/blob/master/test/designdoc.js

Comment: Very useful, digging through that code helped a lot. Thanks